# Derive the equation of the locus of all points (exact question in description)

Tags: calculus

Derive the equation of the locus of all points such that the line joining a point in the locus to the point (6,2) and the line joining the same point to the point (2,6) are perpendicular.

I need help with this proof for my calculus class
 I have a test coming up an I'm having trouble with proofs like this. This is on my study guide. I was able to complete a problem where u had to derive an equation whose points are equidistant from 2 points. I just want to learn how to do itn no need to give me answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let us call $A=(6,2)$ and $B=(2,6)$. If $P$ is a point satisfying the given condition, then
$APB$ is a rectangular triangle.

Consider the middle point between $A$ and $B$, $C=\frac{A+B}{2}$.

Draw a picture.

Edit: (Notation: $||X-Y||$: distance between $X$ and $Y$)
We have,
$$
4||P-C||^2=(P-A+P-B)\cdot(P-A+P-B)=||P-A||^2+||P-B||^2=||A-B||^2
$$
Then we obtain a circunsference with centre $C$ and ratio $\frac{||A-B||}{2}$.

$$
(x-4)^2+(y-4)^2=16
$$

Comment: The midpoint of this triangle is 4,4. Should I try finding the equation from that point to P?

Comment: Yes, Estimate $||P-C||$.

Comment: Yes, the length of the segment PC.

Comment: there is no set value for it but I tried a point the satisfies condition (2,2) so distance would be square root of 8

Comment: square root(4-x)^2+(4-y)^2

Comment: why do u multiply by four in this? (at the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Given that a line passing through $A=(6,2)$ is perpendicular to a line passing through $B=(2,6)$, what does that tell you about the shape formed by those two lines and the line between $A$ and $B$?

Further hint: if the line $AB$ is always opposite a right angle, what does that say about the two lines that meet to make the right angle?

Comment: those two lines are perpendicular right?

Comment: maybe they are equal as well

Comment: More than that, what about how long they are?  Not always equal, I believe...

Comment: both sides are 5?, but I thought P could change as long it satisfies condition. Or is it 5 in every situation?